# Remove shadow under action bar

Tags: android

I started experimenting a bit with android studio. When I check the render in Android Studio, I can see that my app looks perfectly fine, but when I run it on my device there's some sort of shadow under the action bar that's bothering me. I don't know where it comes from because android studio doesn't shows this shadow. The shadow is present on both the nexus 5 and the nexus 7 (both lollipop). Any ideas in how to fix this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12246388/remove-shadow-below-actionbar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For android 5.0, the shadow can be removed using the following code:

```
getSupportActionBar().setElevation(0);    // for support-library actionbar
getActionBar().setElevation(0);    // for non support-library actionbar
```

By the way, about preview in android studio and actual display effect in real device, you can have a look at this link [different of the two display effect](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29001288/4188219)